# Strategy to keep track of third-party ROS packages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, git, third-party

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In my ROS project, I am using ROS packages that can't be installed with apt and need to be cloned and compiled from source.
Because of that, I can't use rosdep to easily download all of the dependencies, which is making things more complicated when the project needs to be setup on a new computer.

What is the strategy people use to make this process easier?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382169/strategy-to-keep-track-of-third-party-ros-packages/) by [JeremieBourque](https://answers.ros.org/users/72248/jeremiebourque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A common strategy if you want to stay within the ROS toolset is using repos files. Its a specification of ROS repos, URLs, branch (or tag or commit hash) that can be cloned automatically via vcstools and then compiled.

There are also plenty of configuration management tools like Ansible, Chef or Puppet for more generalized solutions to do more than just ROS management but installing operating system utilities, installing scripts in particular places, starting daemans, compiling workspaces, etc.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/74436/jaron/) on 2021-07-10**:
You can also use language specific package managers like pip or Conan and use their package tracking methods if they're published in them. Or if they're not, you can git submodules if they're in git. That's the most similar to vcstool.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-07-12**:
I think a link to `vcstool` would be helpful here: https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool (I'm assume you didn't mean to refer to `vcstools` since that's another tool and it's deprecated)

**Comment by [JeremieBourque](https://answers.ros.org/users/72248/jeremiebourque/) on 2021-07-12**:
What are the advantages of using git submodules over vcstool?

**Comment by [Jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/74436/jaron/) on 2021-07-12**:
Simply the fact that it doesn't require another package. For ros packages, I would definitely agree with using vcstool as it's the most common in this community and does more than git submodules. I have used git submodules with projects with and without ros depending on the amount it uses ros or the familiarity with ros I can except from the developers. I only brought it up because I think seeing the whole domain of what people use to answer question is sometimes helpful so you can see the value of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use a bash script to set up on a new machine or update an existing one. For a new machine, the script uses `apt-get` and `git clone` as needed. This approach has worked well for us.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're quite happily using `wstool`. It is deprecated in the favor of `vcstool`, but it works well. You can even have multiple `.rosinstall` files (e.g. per feature) and merge them via `wstool merge` to get a workspace with all dependencies.

There's also a non-written standard (used at least by our team and a lot of packages from ETH Zurich ASL) that each package can have a file `dependencies.rosinstall` in its root, and this specifies its from-source dependencies. We then have a script that recursively walks the workspace and merges all these files to the workspace's `.rosinstall` until all from-source dependencies are satisfied. But it is a bit fragile if e.g. two packages specify the same dependency but with different URL (e.g. one ending with `.git` and one without it).

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2021-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using GitHub submodules might be a solution to your query.

Also have a look at the `wstool` utility and `.rosinstall` file. They might be helpful too.

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2021-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1